# In a rails app, when using Jquery Token Input, how to pre-populate data when the form is reloaded?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-tokeninput

In my form, I use JqueryTokenInput to add tags. When I fill the form and submit, usually, if there are errors the form will load again with the values I entered. But the TokenInput field won't get those values. I tried to do it by loading data from the params like this :

In the view input field :

```
  data: {load: @current_tags}
```

In the controller :

```
  @current_tags = params[:deshana][:deshanatag_list]
```

This doesn't work. I think its not in the right format. How can I do this?

Comment: share you token input data hash.

Answer (score 0):

Buddy i have also used the token input for the auto-complete drop down and here i have doing this which you have asked the question.

May this will defiantly help full for that to compelete your problem.

Write the following line in the start of your javascript tag on the html page.

```
$("#id_of_your_token_input_field").tokenInput(token_input_data,{

prePopulate: [{id: id_of_data, name:name_of_data}]

});
```